# Как получить целое значение из массива PHP?

Tags: php

Через PHP я получаю из MySql ответ из таблицы = [{"s1":81}]

Как мне с помощью PHP вывести только целое число 81 из этого массива [{"s1":81}]
????

Comment: Какие проблемы возникли? Банальную индексацию (`$response[0]["s1"]`, `$response[0]=>{"s1"}`) не можете выучить?

Comment: `var_dump(json_decode('[{"s1":81}]', 1)['s1']);`

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас из базы данных приходят разные значения, вы не знаете их ключей и их может быть много, то можно воспользоваться следующим кодом для вывода значений из базы.

```
 $json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
 foreach (json_decode($json, true) as $value)
 {
     echo $value."<br>"; 
 }
```

Подробнее, можно почитать в [мануале](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) об этом.